# Communicating between multiple layers of nested directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mvvm

It's a bit complex so bear with me. I've got three layers of directives:

1. Top layer - a popup directive
2. Middle layer - a `switch-pane` directive *
3. Bottom layer - one of several views

The top layer is just some popup that represents a wizard in my app.
The middle layer is a directive I've made that acts as a stack of views - you can "push" and "pop" views. The "top" view is displayed and the rest are pushed aside and blurred.
The bottom layer is a bunch of views that are normally unrelated to each other, which are dynamically loaded and displayed in the `switch-pane` according to what the user does.

So far, this works, BUT: currently, the top layer's `$scope` has an array property that represents all the views the `switch-pane` should display, passed to the `switch-pane` directive as an attribute, and the `switch-pane` directives `$watch`es it and updates itself.
This is OK but I don't think it's good enough - I'd like the `switch-pane` directive itself to manage it's stack of views, and only expose a `push` and `pop` API.

Here are a few ways I thought of:

- Using `$broadcast` / `$emit` - the top layer will $broadcast a "push" event and the `switch-pane` will catch it and do whatever it needs
- Using a service (to subscribe and fire the "push" event - this is just like using `$broadcast` but doesn't propagate throughout the scope tree
- Using a service that allows the `switch-pane` directive to register an API of it's own. Using some way of identifying it such as an attribute or even element ID
- Using `angular.element().scope()` to get access to the `switch-pane`'s inner workings

Frankly, I don't like any of these methods much. Certainly I want to avoid being tied to the DOM, so the last 2 are worst.

Any other ways to do this? Which is the most Angular-ish way to expose a directive's API, considering we don't really have access to a **certain instance** of a directive except via DOM?

Comment: Maybe it's worth adding a note: the problem with the `emit` approach and similar "global event" solutions is - identifying the source of the event. If I have 2 of these switch-pane directives, how do I direct my "push" event to a specific one, without binding myself to the current DOM structure? (ie without using the directive's element ID)

Answer (score 0):

You could check how `ng-form`, `ng-model` and `ng-input` is implemented. Basically if the form has a name, for instance `<form name="foo" ...>` its controller is published to the current scope, in this case under `$scope.foo` variable. Once the controller is published you could use its API outside the `ng-form` directive.

You could also access this controller from the other directive if `require: "^ngForm"` option is specified.

Here is an example taken from my project. It's a sort of wrapper for jqGrid grid plugin written in jQuery: https://github.com/9ci/angle-grinder/blob/06856b0d940b572960025f06f470c2f40fdc0ceb/app/scripts/modules/gridz.coffee#L12

Comment: The `require` solution, as demonstrated on Angular's homepage examples and in your answer, are the reverse case from mine - you can use `require: ^parentController` to access the parent's "API" of sorts, but what I need is the parent (the top level) to access some API on a directive contained **within** it.